# How to add image in a button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tk-toolkit

This makes an image:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("960x540+480+200")
load = Image.open("example.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = tk.Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=450, y=280)
tk.mainloop()
```

How do I put image inside a button?

Comment: Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and 
[Tkinter.Widget.bind-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bind-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the image on a button.

```
button1=Button(window , text = 'Click Me !', image = render)
```

Comment: What does the `text='Click Me !'` do? I can not see it on the GUI

Comment: It is because `compound` option is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code...

```
Button(master, text = "Button", image = "image.png", compound=LEFT)
```

Comment: `image="image.png"` will not work. The `image` parameter requires an image, not the name of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code ....

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# creating tkinter window 
root = Tk()

# Adding widgets to the root window 
Label(root, text = 'btn').pack(side = TOP, pady = 10) 
 
# Creating a photoimage object to use image 
photo = PhotoImage(file = r"pic.png") 
  
# here, image option is used to set image on button  
Button(root, text = 'button', image = photo).pack(side = TOP)  
 
mainloop()
```